# EF Code First convention to allow ICollection<T> properties to be empty collections rather than null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I've noticed that, by default, Entity Framework Code First neglects to instantiate `ICollection<T>` properties unless there is at least one item in the collection. I would much prefer that the collection were guaranteed to always be an empty `HashSet` (i.e., a `HashSet` with zero items) rather than `null` if no items exist.

Is there any convention or setting for EF Code First that would enable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the constructor of the entity just set instantiate the collection:

```
public sealed partial class EntityClass
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors",
        Justification = "EF 4.1 requires them to be virtual, and RIA Services requires the collections to be instantiated.")]
    public EntityClass()
    {
        OtherEntities = new List<OtherEntity>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

The suppression message is there for FXcop.